# Xcode telling me that I have an "Incomplete implementation"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, implementation

My teacher has given me this main.m that I must code the .h and .m methods for. In my .m(not main) file I made I am getting an "Incomplete implementation" warning from Xcode. I have made methods for all that were called so I can't figure out why it is saying that. Here is the code given to us that I cannot modify:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ChutesAndLadders.h"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        ChutesAndLadders *cl = [[ChutesAndLadders alloc]init];
        [cl initBoard];
        [cl makeChutes:10];
        [cl makeLadders:10]
        int chutes=0;
        int ladders=0;
        for(int i=0;i<cl.board.count;i++){
            NSString * cell = (NSString *)[cl.board objectAtIndex:i];
            int additionalSpaces = (int)[cl addToMove:cell];
            if(additionalSpaces>0)
                ladders++;
            else if (additionalSpaces<0)
                chutes++;
        }
        [cl printBoard];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the .h that I coded, I believe it is OK:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface ChutesAndLadders : NSObject{
    @private
    NSMutableArray * board;
}
@property (readwrite, retain) NSMutableArray *board;
-(id) initBoard;
-(NSString *)addToMove: (NSString *) cell;
-(void)makeChutes: (int) length;
-(void)makeLadders: (int) length;
-(void)printBoard;
@end
```

Here is my .m which is where I'm having the problem at the "@implementation ChutesAndLadders" line:

```
#import "ChutesAndLadders.h"
@implementation ChutesAndLadders//incomplete impementation????????????
@synthesize board=_board;
-(void) initBoard{
    //self = [super init];
    //if (self){
        _board = [board initWithCapacity: 100];
        //self._board=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:100];
        for(int i =0; i < 100; i++){
            [_board addObject:@""];
        //}
    }
}
-(void)makeChutes: (int) length {
    //Make argument number of Chutes randomly across the board.
    for(int i = 0; i < length;){
        int random = arc4random_uniform(101);
        if ([[_board objectAtIndex:random] isEqual:@""]) {
            NSString *fString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"C%d", length];
            [_board replaceObjectAtIndex:random withObject:fString];
            i++;
        }
    }
}
-(void)makeLadders: (int) length {
    //Make argument number of Ladders randomly across the board.
     for(int i = 0; i < length;){
        int random = arc4random_uniform(101);
        if ([[_board objectAtIndex:random] isEqual:@""]) {
                NSString *fString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"L%d", length];
            [_board replaceObjectAtIndex:random withObject:fString];
            i++;
        }
    }
}
-(NSString *)addToMove: (NSString*) cell {
    if([[_board objectAtIndex:[cell integerValue]] isEqualToString:@"C10"]){
        return (@"-10");
     }
    if([[_board objectAtIndex:[cell integerValue]] isEqualToString:@"L10"]){
        return (@"10");
    }
     else
        return (@"0"); 
}
-(void) printboard {
    //Print the board in rows of 10 so that it looks like a square in console.
    for(int i=0; i < (_board.count/10); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            NSLog(@"|");
            NSLog(@"%@", [_board objectAtIndex:(i+j)]);
            NSLog(@"|");
        }
        NSLog(@"\n");
    }
}
@end
```

This is my first assignment in Objective-C, Macs in general for that matter, and I've been at it for some time, mostly research/studing and I just can't see what I'm doing wrong.

I have not ran this program so sorry for any other stupid errors you may see, I will figure them out once I can actually get it to output to the console so I can see if it is doing what it is suppose to.

Comment: you defined -(void)initBoard, but declared -(id)initBoard. Also no need to add a @synthesize directive or declare a _board ivar. It's also not necessary to specify `readwrite` for a read/write property, that's the default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the Issue navigator via the triangle/exclamation mark button at upper-left:

[image]

If you expand your "Incomplete implementation" Semantic Issue with the little triangle at left, you can see the details of XCode's complaint.

Comment: Wooowww, I've looked at that screen a hundred times, did not realize that the arrow next to Semantic Issue could be clicked and expanded.

Answer (score 2):

The `initBoard` method has different return type in `m` file. Also, Objective-C is case sensitive. `printBoard` and `printboard` are not equal for obj-c compiler.
BTW. You should use `init...` name only for constructors. See [Naming Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-BCIGIJJF) doc from Apple.

Answer (score 1):

In your .h file, there's a method named `-(void)printBoard;` But in your .m file, its name is `-(void)printboard`. Objective-C is case intensive.

And also, the `-(id)initBoard;` and `-(void)initBoard`.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `addToMove` and `printBoard` in the header file, but they are missing in the .m file. That is the reason for the warning.

Comment: Nope, the OP do implement these two, just scroll down the code and you'll find them.

Comment: Ah, yes, my mistake. But the printBoard function needs to be with a capital B.

Comment: Yep, that's the one I just got.